# How to use try-except to skip the case that selenium is unable to locate element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, try-except, nosuchelementexception

My question is how to use try-expect to skip the case that selenium is unable to locate element.
For some reasons, I have to skip the situation described above.I want to use try-expect, but I don’t know what to write after except.

I use Python version 3.8.6, chromeriver version 87.0.4280.88, and selenium version number 3.141.0，window 10

for example():

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https:www.google.com")
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cdNav"]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a').click()
except:
    pass
```

The current error occurred:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div/nav/ul/li[5]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

Normally,I could write `IndentationError`, `SyntaxError` and so on, but I dont 't  know  what type of error to write after EXPECT in above case.

This problem has troubled me for a long time, I hope it can be solved, thank you very much

Comment: "but I dont 't know what type of error to write after EXPECT in above case." - did you try using the name **that appears in the error message**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### find_element_by_xpath()

[`find_element_by_xpath()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) returns [NoSuchElementException](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) if the element wasn't found.

So ideally you need to catch *NoSuchElementException* and your effective code block will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https:www.google.com")
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cdNav"]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a').click()
except nosuchelementexception:
    pass
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: I know the reason finally.
I should write `import selenium`,not `from selenium import *`
And the error type should be `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @Alen Apologies, I should have added the import earlier within my answer.